# How to show the title for nsys profile?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, nsight-systems

I have noticed that when I use nsys in my machine

```
nsys profile --stats=true -o output-report ./input
```

It outputs the data like this:

```
NVIDIA Nsight Systems version 2022.4.2.50-32196742v0


[5/8] Executing 'cudaapisum' stats report

Time (%)  Total Time (ns)  Num Calls    Avg (ns)      Med (ns)     Min (ns)    Max (ns)    StdDev (ns)            Name         
 --------  ---------------  ---------  ------------  ------------  ----------  -----------  ------------  ----------------------
     46.7      100,404,793          3  33,468,264.3      22,463.0      12,434  100,369,896  57,938,512.8  cudaMallocManaged     
     39.5       84,938,847          1  84,938,847.0  84,938,847.0  84,938,847   84,938,847           0.0  cudaDeviceSynchronize 
     13.8       29,677,781          3   9,892,593.7   9,610,457.0   9,514,092   10,553,232     574,154.9  cudaFree              
      0.0           82,478          1      82,478.0      82,478.0      82,478       82,478           0.0  cuLibraryLoadData     
      0.0           40,588          1      40,588.0      40,588.0      40,588       40,588           0.0  cudaLaunchKernel      
      0.0              892          1         892.0         892.0         892          892           0.0  cuModuleGetLoadingMode
```

The section is described by "Executing 'cudaapisum' stats report" instead of the normal title like "CUDA API Statistics". So I'm wondering if there's a flag that I can use to output the stats like the one below:

The output below isn't from my machine, it's from AWS's machine.

```
NVIDIA Nsight Systems version 2021.1.1.66-6c5c5cb


CUDA API Statistics:

 Time(%)  Total Time (ns)  Num Calls    Average     Minimum    Maximum           Name         
 -------  ---------------  ---------  -----------  ---------  ---------  ---------------------
    61.5        250696605          3   83565535.0      36197  250541972  cudaMallocManaged    
    32.8        133916228          1  133916228.0  133916228  133916228  cudaDeviceSynchronize
     5.7         23226526          3    7742175.3    6373371    9064987  cudaFree             
     0.0            56395          1      56395.0      56395      56395  cudaLaunchKernel
```

And the other thing I have to mention is that on my machine it automatically outputs the profile file to a .nsys-rep extension not the .qdrep extension. Are both of them the same or different?

I've been trying to find information in the [nsys](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-systems/UserGuide/index.html#cli-profiling) documentation, but I couldn't find any. I've tried searching in stackoverflow & [nvidia's](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/development-tools/nsight-systems/116) forum on Nsight but none came up so far. Maybe I've missed something. Any help will be appreciated.

Note: both of them is using the same command but just a slightly different file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And the other thing I have to mention is that on my machine it automatically outputs the profile file to a .nsys-rep extension not the .qdrep extension. Are both of them the same or different?

`.nsys-rep` is the new extension name for `.qdrep` files, it is the same format though. The change happened with version *2021.4*.

Specifically, from the [release notes](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-systems/2021.4/ReleaseNotes/index.html#whats-new) of the aforementioned version:

> Result file rename
>
> - In order to make the Nsight tools family more consistent, all versions of Nsight Systems starting with 2021.4 will use the “.nsys-rep” extension for generated report files by default.
> - Older versions of Nsight Systems used “.qdrep”.
> - Nsight Systems GUI 2021.4 and higher will continue to support opening older “.qprep” reports.
> - Versions of Nsight Systems GUI older than 2021.4 will not be able to open “.nsys-rep” reports.

Please note that the versions of the tool on your local machine and the AWS machine are different.

> So I'm wondering if there's a flag that I can use to output the stats like the one below

There isn't a flag to control the output you are mentioning. You could modify your workflow slightly, profile your application without the `--stats` CLI switch, and collect the report file (`nsys-rep`/`qdrep`). Then you can use the [nsys stats](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-systems/UserGuide/index.html#cli-stats-command-switch-options) command and apply specific stats reports to your report file.

If you have feature requests for the Nsight Systems tool, please let us know through the [NVIDIA Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/development-tools/nsight-systems/116).